# Pythonのライブラリで、デバッグ用に標準出力する方法（print文でよい？）

Tags: python

#### 背景

Pythonでライブラリを作成しています。
REST APIをラップしたものです。
`pip isntall`でインストールされることを前提としています。

#### 質問

ライブラリ内でデバッグ用にprint文を使っていますが、以下の点で良くないと考えています。

- デバッグ用の標準出力のON/OFFを切り替えられない

ライブラリでデバッグ用に標準出力したい場合、どのようなコードを書くべきでしょうか？

具体的には、以下のようなコードです。

```
def get_hoge(self):
    if not self.is_authenticated():
        print("not logined")
        self.login()

    requests.get("https://hoge.co.jp/hoge")
```

#### 追記（分からなかったこと）

いろいろなサイトを見て、print文を使うのはよくないということが分かりました。
しかし標準ライブラリの`http.client.HTTPConnection`では、以下のようにprint文を使っていたので、疑問に思いました。

```
def _read_status(self):
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    if len(line) > _MAXLINE:
        raise LineTooLong("status line")
    if self.debuglevel > 0:
        print("reply:", repr(line))
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/client.py#L260

また、https://qiita.com/amedama/items/b856b2f30c2f38665701 を読みましたがよく分からず、特にloggingとloggerの違いが分かりませんでした。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

loggerを使いましょう。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/logging.html

使い方については、以下に説明があります
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: loggingとloggerは何が違うのでしょうか？どう使い分ければよいのでしょうか？

Comment: logging はモジュール名です。loggerはインスタンス名です。Pythonのモジュール・ライブラリのことを厳密に指す場合は「loggingモジュールを使いましょう」と書くべきでした。Python以外の言語も含めて一般的に表現する場合は「logger（ロガー）」と表現します。